# Can the output of a shell command executed inside a vim script be redirected to a file?

Tags: vim, tags, ctags

I am trying to generate tags for Go projects for vim. As ctags does not have native support for go I am using [gotags](https://github.com/jstemmer/gotags) for it. I wrote a small vim function to check if the file is .go and if so to use the gotags and not ctags:

```
    function! g:GenerateTags()
        if &filetype == 'go'
            !gotags -R -f tags .
        else
            !ctags -R .
        endif
    endfunction
```

This works fine with other languages, but gotags just outputs to the console not to a file. I have also tried with:

```
system('gotags -R -f tags .')
system('gotags -R . > tags')
execute !gotags -R . > tags
```

But still the output is directed to the console.

Is there a way to redirect it to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had a typo in the version in my vimrc as I tried again with the first version posted here and it worked:

```
    function! g:GenerateTags()
        if &filetype == 'go'
             !gotags -R -f tags .
        else
            !ctags -R .
        endif
    endfunction
```